# Не могу понять что синтаксис oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle

```
ALTER TABLESPACE PROBATBS ADD DATAFILE 'C:\ORACLE\ORADATA\PROBA\PRBTWO.DAT'
SIZE 50M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M MAXSIZE 100M
```

То что он создаст базу с изначальным размером 10мегабайт и будет расширятся до 100мегабайт это понятно. А вот что это подразумевает `"ON NEXT 10M"`? что он будет делать на 10 мегабайт.

Answer (score 2):

Изначально создаст 50 М

расширять будет по 10 М

максимальный размер 100 М

REUSE - будет использовать удаленные ячейки

**UPDATE**

команда

```
ALTER TABLESPACE PROBATBS ADD DATAFILE 'C:\ORACLE\ORADATA\PROBA\PRBTWO.DAT'
SIZE 50M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M MAXSIZE 100M
```

добавляет новый файл в разделе `C:` для `Tablespace` `PROBATBS` дополнительный файл размером `50М`. Этот раздел может увеличиватся до `100М` с шагом `10М` автоматически. То есть, файл когда достигнет 100М он дальше не будет увеличиваться.

если вам нужно еще расширить этот tablespace вы можете сделать это используя другой диск. к примеру

```
ALTER TABLESPACE PROBATBS ADD DATAFILE 'D:\ORACLE\ORADATA\PROBA\PRBT_2.DAT'
SIZE 50M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M
```

тут как видите нету `MAXSIZE 100M` он будет расширятся до упора

а *удаленные ячейки (мусор)* будет сам автоматически очищать. Главное что бы в `С:` диске всегда было место до `100М`

P.S. добавил Update после комментариев

Comment: а если так будет SIZE 10M AUTOEXTEND ON MAXSIZE 100M; никаких косяков не возникнет в работе с субд, и вообще нужны ли удаленные ячейки? если допустим размер базы будет 150гигабайт

Comment: база будет временно медленно работать при увеличении размера. И главное что бы место на винчесторе хватало. ато автосайз не сможет работать. 1) А 150ГБ обшая база это не проблема, все будет нормально работать. 2) удаленные ячейки лучще пусть использует. Когда база становится грязной (много удаленных ячеек) само автоматом запустит очистку. так что все нормально.

Comment: я начинающий, и чёт не со всем понял щас на деле. расширяю с reuse (SIZE 50M REUSE AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M MAXSIZE 100M), проверяю доступное место на табличном пространстве он увеличивает на 50М, а не на 100М. т.е он автоматом будет подкидывать по 10 мегабайт? и не стоит переживать что там 99% занято, оно всё равно увеличивать будет?

Answer (score 2):

Ребята,

- нет никаких "автоочистка сама запустится"
- REUSE - это не про "ячейки", это говорит о том, что если файл с таким именем уже существует, команда не выпадет с ошибкой, а переиспользует (перезатрет) существующий файл
- ячеек, кстати, тоже нет - есть блоки данных, но сейчас тут у вас речь не про них
- если авторасширение (autoextend) настроено для табличного пространства - тот факт, что в нем периодически будет 99% занято - не проблема, как только Оракл не сможет выделить очередной *экстент*, файл данных расширится на значение, указанное в NEXT

Answer (score 1):

При необходимости расширит размер пространства:

AUTOEXTEND ON - включает функцию авторасширения размера файла

NEXT 10M - минимальный размер приращения к размеру файла при расширении

Полезные ссылки:

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/dfiles003.htm

http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_alter_autoextend_on.htm